# Building and testing component with docker and jmeter during gitlab CI/CD pipeline

Tags: docker, jmeter, gitlab

I'm currently working on a project where I have a component in gitlab that I run through a CI/CD pipeline whenever there is a change to it. This runs a few junit tests etc
I want to be able to mount the snapshot zip file in docker when the pipeline is finished and build the image so I can run a few jmeter tests. I need the component in order to do these tests.
My question is, would I be able to do this during the end of the pipeline?

I know you can run a few scripts in the projects gitlab-ci.yml file, can I add my docker image to the yml file and my jmeter cli command line?

I want to build and mount the image in docker during pipeline, run the jmeter tests and then get a log of the results basically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know *exactly* how to accomplish what you're after, but you could create a job in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` to build the image and push it up with your component as an artifact. Then you could have another stage to pull down the image and run any jMeter tests against the container you want. Without seeing your current cfg, it's sorta hard to tell where you are progress-wise, but hopefully this helps a little. Good luck!

```yaml
stages:
  ...
  - jmeter


test stage:
  image: your_pushed_image_with_component
  stage: jmeter
  script: 
    - cli cmd to run jMeter against running container
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 week
    paths:
      - test_results
```